# What is the number of stages in Earth Defense Force 2025?

Tags: earth-defense-force-2025

I'm playing EDF 2025 and I'm already at stage 68. How long is the game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 85 stages in EDF 2025 and 95 stages in EDF 2025 online.

Source: http://theearthdefenseforce.wikia.com/wiki/Levels